# MasterPageFile with an ABSOLUTE url?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I'm hosting a web on a server (the server is not on my pc). When I need to debug a page sometimes I download it from the server and test it locally. When this page is using a masterpage I can't access it.

I can't use the tilde in the "masterpagefile=" because the masterpage is not on the local pc, but online, that's why I wanted to use an absolute url like: MasterPageFile="http://www.pcgroup.co.il/MasterPages/menu.Master". But this is giving me an error that it is not a virtual path.

Any workaround? (please don't reply: download the masterpage and then edit it, I'm looking for something more elegent than that..).
Thank you all.

Comment: Where is the source of the web application? Why not test from where the development is taking place so that you have the masterpage local?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The masterpagefile property [must point to a virtual path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.masterpagefile.aspx). Is the masterpage in a physical directory that you have access to? In other words could you get to the masterpage via a UNC file path like \server\share\masterpages\menu.master? If so, you could create a Virtual Directory on your local IIS that points to that path. Call the virtual directory something like remote. Then you should be able to use ~/remote/[rest of the path here].

Comment: just to add, if that masterpage is not on the intranet an IIS server will not serve the `.masterpage` file to you and give an error trying to load it as a URI.

Comment: Ok, the file is not on the same intranet, @Eonasdan - thank you for that remark.. just for "fun" I've been trying to create a virtual dir with a redirection to a url on my server (I copied the master page to my server just for the test) - http://localhost/q , but when running it I get this error: `'The file '/ContactForm2/tst2/menu.Master'` does not exist'. (tst2 is the name of the virtual path redirected to http://localhost/q). I'm using iis 5 (winxp).  @Zach Green - how do I test from the server itself? I'm using ftp client and edit the aspx file (which means download it to my pc)?

Comment: so why don't you download the masterpage or have one locally so you can use the `"~/PATH"` method? I've test developed and migrated all files, including a master page, when I did asp.net classic development.

Comment: @Eonasdan - I just wanted to make sure I'm not working like a fool, it didn't make sense that I have to "rebuild" my project every time when working on a remote server, I thought asp.net supposed to make life easier.. but if that's the way to work at least I know I'm not an idiot, that's also worth something :) Your help is appreciated.

Comment: typically, that's how *I* work. Work on a local dev server and then upload/migrate/deploy to a live server. The obvious benefit of an "uh oh" prevention :) doesn't mean someone doesn't have a better solution, that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: IMHO the best way to handle this problem is via your source control software. I use Mercurial and Git but any one should provide the ability for you to pull all updated project resources down to your local environment in a single command line or click.